# Oracle How to get the birthday list from last 15 days to next 15 days?

Tags: oracle

I've a table with employees and their birth date, in a column in a format string.
I cannot modify the table, so I created a view to get their birth date in a real date format (TO_DATE).

Now, I would like to get the list of the employees having theirs birthday in the last 15 days and the employees who'll have theirs birthday in the next 15 days.
So, just based with the Day and the month.

I successfully get for exemple all employees bornt in April with "Extract", but, I'm sure you've already understand, when I'll run the query the 25 April, I'd like the futures birthday in May.

How could I get that (oracle 12c)

Thank you

Comment: The problem is even more interesting than the example you gave. If "today" is January 10, you will want people born this month (birth date between January 1 and January 25), but also people with birthday in the last five days of December.

Comment: Indeed! Happy to see I made a comprehensive message 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `hiredate` column in table `scott.emp` for testing:

```
select empno, ename, hiredate
from   scott.emp
where  add_months(trunc(hiredate), 
                  12 * round(months_between(sysdate, hiredate) / 12))
       between trunc(sysdate) - 15 and trunc(sysdate) + 15
;

     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE  
---------- ---------- ----------
      7566 JONES      04/02/1981
      7698 BLAKE      05/01/1981
      7788 SCOTT      04/19/1987
```

This will produce the wrong result in the following situation: if someone's birthday is Feb. 28 in a non-leap year, their birthday in a leap year (calculated with the ADD_MONTHS function in the query) will be considered to be Feb. 29. So, they will be excluded if running the query on, say, Feb. 13 2024 (even though they should be included), and they will be included if running the query on March 14 (even though they should be excluded). If you can live with this - those people will be recognized in the wrong window, once every four years - then this may be all you need. Otherwise that situation will require further tweaking.

For people born on Feb. 29 (in a leap year, obviously), their birthday in a non-leap-year is considered to be Feb. 28. With this convention, the query will always work correctly for them. Whether this convention is appropriate in your locale, only your business users can tell you. (Local laws and regulations may matter, too - depending on what you are using this for.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ddd` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A):

DDD - Day of year (1-366).

For example:

```sql
SQL> with v(dt) as (
  2      select date'2020-01-01'+level-1 from dual connect by date'2020-01-01'+level-1<date'2021-01-01'
  3  )
  4  select *
  5  from v
  6  where
  7   not abs(
  8         to_number(to_char(date'&dt','ddd'))
  9        -to_number(to_char(dt       ,'ddd'))
 10       ) between 15 and 350;
Enter value for dt: 2022-01-03

DT
-------------------
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-01-02 00:00:00
2020-01-03 00:00:00
2020-01-04 00:00:00
2020-01-05 00:00:00
2020-01-06 00:00:00
2020-01-07 00:00:00
2020-01-08 00:00:00
2020-01-09 00:00:00
2020-01-10 00:00:00
2020-01-11 00:00:00
2020-01-12 00:00:00
2020-01-13 00:00:00
2020-01-14 00:00:00
2020-01-15 00:00:00
2020-01-16 00:00:00
2020-01-17 00:00:00
2020-12-19 00:00:00
2020-12-20 00:00:00
2020-12-21 00:00:00
2020-12-22 00:00:00
2020-12-23 00:00:00
2020-12-24 00:00:00
2020-12-25 00:00:00
2020-12-26 00:00:00
2020-12-27 00:00:00
2020-12-28 00:00:00
2020-12-29 00:00:00
2020-12-30 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00

30 rows selected.
```

NB: This example doesn't analyze leap years.

Comment: "Doesn't analyze leap years" deserves some explanation. The query may return the wrong answer (wrong window - off by one day) for birthdays after March 1 in a leap year but "reference date" (such as "today") after March 1 in a non-leap year, or vice versa - and for a few other combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [mathguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71898062/1509264), but translating the current date back to the birth year (rather than translating the birth year forwards):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  birth_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(
                            TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                            ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(birth_date, SYSDATE)/12)*12
                          ) - INTERVAL '15' DAY
                      AND ADD_MONTHS(
                            TRUNC(SYSDATE),
                            ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(birth_date, SYSDATE)/12)*12
                          ) + INTERVAL '15' DAY;
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (name, birth_date) AS
SELECT 'Alice', DATE '2020-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Betty', DATE '2020-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', DATE '2021-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', DATE '2022-04-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', DATE '2021-03-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiona', DATE '2021-03-31' FROM DUAL;
```

If today's date is 2022-04-16 then the output is:

> | NAME | BIRTH_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | Debra | 28-APR-22 |

If today's date is 2022-03-15 then the output is:

> | NAME | BIRTH_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | Betty | 29-FEB-20 |
> | Carol | 28-FEB-21 |
> | Emily | 30-MAR-21 |

And would get values from 28th February - 30th March in a non-leap-year and from 29th February - 30th March in a leap year.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b6cfea510c98716fc2899117e39be001)*

Comment: This solution will have exceptions similar to mine. If "today" is 28 February 2022, someone born on February 13 (any year) should be included. But if they were born in 2000, "today" moved back to year 2000 becomes 29 Feb, and based on the 15 day window, their birthday will not be included. Conversely if "today" is 29 Feb 2024, someone born on Feb. 13 (any year) should not be included. But if they were born in a non-leap year, "today" transported back will be 28 Feb and their birthday WILL be included.